# Moving a section of app.config to a separate file

Tags: .net, configuration, app-config

for an easiness of my application I would need to have "runtime" element of app.config in separate file.

Tried something like

```
<runtime file="runtime.conf" />
```

and also

```
<runtime configFile="runtime.conf" />
```

and in runtime.conf I have:

```
<runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">  
            .......
    </assemblyBinding>
</runtime>
```

But it is ignored ...

Is there a way to find out what is wrong.

Of course when I copy runtime section directly into app.config it works.

I somewhere found that when using configFile="..." included file must lay in a subdirectory. Tried it but it also doesn't work...

Seems including is not working for runtime section.

Comment: one draw back is that asp.net runtime does not detect when the external file like runtime.config changes. Are you failing to get the values after the runtime.config is changed

Comment: any final solution about it ?

Answer (score 4):

You can't use configSource to externalize the <runtime> configuration.

<runtime> is  a special case that doesn't read the values in any external file specified in configSource.

Specifying the "configSource" attribute won't cause an error, the source file simply won't be read.

More information here: http://world.episerver.com/Blogs/Magnus-Rahl/Dates/2011/6/Todays-gotcha-configSource-on-the-runtime-section-element/

- Including speculation that this is [related to the "IgnoreSection"](http://world.episerver.com/Blogs/Magnus-Rahl/Dates/2011/6/Todays-gotcha-configSource-on-the-runtime-section-element/#comment1613) type information.

Comment: A shame, because this is precisely the one section with a lot of boilerplate "config" likely repeated among various projects in a solution... :-(

Answer (score 2):

Hi is your runtime.conf is in your bin folder of the application

Comment: It is exactly in the directory where app.config is.

Comment: But app.config is usually copied to bin as <appname>.exe.config. Is your runtime.config also copied to the bin folder when you build?

Comment: This should be marked as the correct answer. I was having the exact same issue. I changed the Copy to Output Directory to Copy Always, and it worked.

Answer (score 2):

You can load binding redirect configuration from external file using `linkedConfiguration` element https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/configure-apps/file-schema/linkedconfiguration-element

```
<configuration>
  <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
    <linkedConfiguration href="file://c:\Program Files\Contoso\sharedConfig.xml"/>
  </assemblyBinding>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Could'nt make it works with an wcf app. What do you put in the sharedConfig.xml ? Do you repeat the 'assemblybinding' root ? or the root is the 'runtime' section ? Thank you

Comment: I've never used it. This example is from aforementioned documentation

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<runtime configSource="runtime.conf"/>
```

Comment: unfortunately the same result. I was trying it with configSource first and than also with "file" and copied code to my answer... But originally it should be "configSource", it simple ignores it damn :D

Comment: Theoretically the correct attribute to specify, but runtime is a special case that won't read the configSource value. Learned from testing.